# Is there any dynamic action event to detect apex error event

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I want to add CSS to the error message div in oracle apex application such that this will only trigger when any validation error occurs in the oracle apex

Tried with DOMsubtree modified event but as the function depricated with several performance issues, I am now looking into some other way to do it

I am expecting if we can trace an event when an error message displayed in oracle apex I can acheive the remaining

Comment: What is exactly you're tring to do? I'm not convinced this is necessarily the answer. xyproblem.info

Comment: I had a specific set of error, warning and information messages with validations in oracle apex, I just want to change the color of message box to red, yellow or blue respectively. The message box by default always shows yellow color.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment said, not sure what you want. But you can do custom validations with custom error messages.

Or you could also be dealing with the error handling function where you can do whatever you want with it, not sure how to add CSS, but you can rename basic server errors there, log errors,... So perhaps you can acomplish what you want there.

You get to it from Shared Components-Application definition- Error handling, and you can set your custom error handling function there.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into several options provided by Oracle Apex Javascript API's I found a function in apex.message namespace.

setThemeHooks is the function which runs any function just before the error message is called by apex ajax functions.